# Autodesk Viewer: Suggestions for 2D view of floor view

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a revit file and am able to convert it via the cloud to a svf and view it in the 3D viewer. It works both as conversion of the .rvt file directly and as an export from the navisworks addin exporter.

My question:
I want the user of my app to also be able to see the floor 2D view as you can in revit.

I have looked through all the manifest files and do not see a f2d for the floor view.

What do you suggest I use for the 2D view?  Note that I will have many drawings to process/view so I would prefer not to have to export a dwg for each view then convert those. I am hoping there is a special setting I can pass to the the converter that will create the 2D views

(Note : I also want to be able to highlight/texture the rooms of this view dynamically. So I will need to be able to access the geometry like you can in the 3D viewer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik all 2D views defined in the Revit project file are automatically translated and included in the Forge output. Have you looked at the LmvNav sample, for instance?

https://calm-inlet-4387.herokuapp.com

It displays both 2D and 3D views.

Note the list of available 2D views in the Secondary View dropdown:

[image: Default 3D and selected 2D secondary view]

It even links the elements in the two views so that anything selected in one is highlighted in the other:

[image: Selected element synchronisation across views]

You could check from where it gets the 2D streams. The source is on GitHub:

https://github.com/JimAwe/LmvNavTest

I think you select whether you want a 2D or a 3D stream when you supply it to the viewer.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  It looks like they are using  Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties  to get the Secondary 2D Views.  For some reason my exports do not have any 2D files in their manifest for the getSubItems to work. I will keep searching before I mark your answers as correct. 

for example [hotel.rvt](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/hotel.rvt)  I do not see any 2D in manifest even though it has floor 1 and 2

Comment: I wasnt able to get the views to convert. It turns out if you make revit "sheets" then the derivative api will produce the f2d files . Which is all I needed. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: thank you for the feedback! questions: 1. so it is solved now? 2. so the 2D views are not embedded in the main SVF? 3. so the 2D views generate separate f2d JSON streams? 4. you call them files, because you save the JSON to a file? 4 times yes/no, please  :-)  thank you!

Comment: 1(yes)
2(no)The way I am using the revit converted svf is to unzip it and get the manifest from inside and pull all the related files. I do not see the normal floor ,ceeling views as f2d inside the manifest.
3(yes sort of)If I first create sheets in the revit file and pull the views into those sheets. Then when I convert the rvt file it will now have f2d of the sheets available in the original manifest that comes from the conversion
4(-) I call them files because the sheets show up a files to access in the conversion manifest

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jeremy's, FYI - If you are looking for a way with already published model, this does not help. But still you may want to be aware if case you are not - If you have a revit model, there is a UI tool to choose views you wish to include.

https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/selecting-views-to-publish-revit-project-on-a360/