# Autodesk Forge Viewer : how to get document

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to get a list of all the 2d and 3d models that go with a converted rvt file.

Looking at the older [example : LmvNavTest](https://github.com/JimAwe/LmvNavTest) they do something like this to get access to the "document" rootItem

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(fullUrnStr, function(document) {
    _loadedDocument = document; // keep this in a global var so we can reference it in other spots

        // get all the 3D and 2D views (but keep in separate arrays so we can differentiate in the UX)
    _views3D = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(document.getRootItem(), {'type':'geometry', 'role':'3d'}, true);
    _views2D = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(document.getRootItem(), {'type':'geometry', 'role':'2d'}, true);
```

From my understanding the prefered way now is to use loadModel

```
oViewer =new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D ($("#viewerContainer") [0], {}) ;
oViewer.loadModel (url , [],  onLoadSuccess, onLoadFail) ;
```

If i do it the loadModel way how do I get access to the document so that I can call its getSubItemsWithProperties method

Comment: sorry for not answering faster. is this resolved now? it appears so, judging from your comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533258/autodesk-viewer-suggestions-for-2d-view-of-floor-view/39533388. or is that situation completely different?

Comment: No I am still confused on where to get "document" from if you load the model directly. Keep in mind that I am trying to do this all offline. So I want to download all the files I need. Specially when dealing with 2D (f2d).  I know that the manifest and the metadata files are in the same folder as the f2d file. But I dont know how to  access the rest of the info in the f2d file since it is not a open format.  I was trying to use the getSubItemsWithProperties method but I dont know how to get the document so i can pass in the rootItem.

Comment: have you checked the new boilerplate samples? https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-boilers.nodejs the first sample is 1 - viewer-offline... it may be doing exactly what you want out of the box.

Comment: When you get a chance, please mark my answer as solution, or clarify in which way it doesn't address your issue and I will elaborate if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are asking the question is a bit confusing and it's hard to understand your workflow if you are not very explicit about what you load offline or not.

Here are the 2 scenario which I think are possible:

1/ You load the model online from Autodesk Cloud using its URN: In that case you need to first to invoke ***Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load***, this call will actually return manifest data, from there you can retrieve the 3D and 2D viewable items using ***Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties*** as you pointed out. Once you have selected - programmatically or by user interaction - the path that you want to load in the viewer, you use ***viewer.loadModel(_views2D[idx])***

2/ You have download locally the whole package of a model, in that case you should already know what are the existing 2D and 3D views because you have some logic that has parsed the resource and stored each viewable. Typically you would need to store this info in a .json or alike file.

You do NOT need to use ***Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load*** in that case, you can directly use ***viewer.loadModel('path/of/the/view/you want to load on your local disk')***

Once you have the model offline, there is no way to "know" what are the existing views, unless your code created a .json that contains this data.

Take a look at this article for more details about how to extract programmatically resources associated with a translated Forge model: [Forge SVF Extractor in Node.js](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs)

Hope that clarifies things, if you have a different scenario, please explain how you proceed.