# Autodesk Platform Services (Forge) Viewer with self-hosted/offline models

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm developing a configurator and to view our 3D model I'm using the Autodesk Viewer.

It is sometimes a bit laggy/slow so I wanted to experiment hosting the models myself to see if this improves loading speed. I found the example https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample/tree/gh-pages here and after adapting this I can succesfully load my model from the public directory.

However, I am only able to set the model on initialization of the viewer. I would like to load the models dynamically from a react app.

I adapted the react wrapper from here: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/viewer-react-sample/blob/master/src/components/Viewer.jsx

But loading the model only works when I load it in the initialization:

```
    this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D(this.container);
    this.viewer.start(this.props.path);
```

Is it possible to dynamically load nodes/models in the same manner as when fetching the models from the app OSS? Below does not load the model. Eventually I would like to try to load the models from my own server i.c.m. the AggregatedView / Loading multiple models.

```
  onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
    this.viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry()),
    console.log('loaded document node')
  }

  updateViewerState(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.path && this.props.path !== prevProps.path) {
      Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(this.props.path, (doc) =>

        onDocumentLoadSuccess(),
        // failure
        (code, message, errors) => console.error(code, message, errors),
      );
    }
    else if (!this.props.path && this.viewer.model) {
      this.viewer.unloadModel(this.viewer.model);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you set the environment to `Local` as in your linked [sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample/blob/8ad97b6bd60f22098701c7599e5e99fa597fe925/index.html#L23)

Comment: Yes I did. The model does load, but just as argument in the viewer.start() method. I can't seem to load the model correctly using Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load. I guess I could refresh the viewer completely when I need another model. But as written in my post I'm hoping to aggregate multiple offline models.

Answer (score 1):

- In the case of `Document.load()` you have to pass in a **URN** or the **URL** to a `bubble.json` file.
- In the case of `loadModel()` (that `Viewer.start()` uses as well) you have to pass in a **URN** or the **URL** to a `*.svf` file. This is what you'd need to use.

Further info that still seems more or less correct:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39758123/4654233

Comment: Thanks Adam. Got a bit further since my post and figured out loadModel is the way to load models by url!