# Viewing Revit floor plans (2D views) in the Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am interested in displaying Revit floor plans on the web, using the Forge Viewer.

Accessing the 3D view and sheet views has been straightforward, using Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties ([link](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/document/)). However, I am unable to find any reference to accessing floor plan views (*not* sheet views) in the documentation.

A similar question was asked here ([Autodesk Viewer: Suggestions for 2D view of floor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533258/autodesk-viewer-suggestions-for-2d-view-of-floor-view)), but the conclusion is unclear - the original poster only seemed to access sheet views.

My question is: are Revit floor plan views accessible from the Forge Viewer? Or, is it meant to only expose 3D views and sheet views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-reading the previous question that you pointed to, [Autodesk Viewer: Suggestions for 2D view of floor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533258/autodesk-viewer-suggestions-for-2d-view-of-floor-view), and its comments more carefully, I have the impression that the Collaboration for Revit tool or C4R add-in mentioned there allows you select addition views to include in the translation, both 2D and 3D:

https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/selecting-views-to-publish-revit-project-on-a360/

You might also want to check out the possibility of driving this functionality programmatically:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/07/selecting-views-for-forge-translation.html