# 2d Sheets in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit

We are showing Autodesk Revit models in Forge Viewer that have 3d views and 2d views.  However, only the 3d view is showing in the Forge Viewer and there is no button available for us to navigate to the 2d view.

Do we need to add an extension to enable display of 3d views + 2d sheet views in Forge Viewer?

We need a toggle like what exists in the  Fusion Viewer

[image]

Comment: Maybe try to load ‘Autodesk.DocumentBrowser’ extension, if you want to list all viewables in the model and switch them as Fusion team does.

Answer (score 0):

I found several useful answers to this question of yours searching the Internet
for [forge viewer revit 2d sheet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=forge+viewer+revit+2d+sheet).

Two of the answers providing background information and solutions for this are right here on StackOverflow:

- [Viewing Revit floor plans (2D views) in the Forge Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631060/viewing-revit-floor-plans-2d-views-in-the-forge-viewer)
- [Autodesk Viewer: Suggestions for 2D view of floor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533258/autodesk-viewer-suggestions-for-2d-view-of-floor-view)

The final answer by Mikako Harada to the latter of these two suggests:

If you have access to the RVT model within Revit on the desktop, you can use the user interface to choose the views you wish to include, also discussed by The Building Coder:

- [Selecting Views to Publish Revit Project on A360](https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/selecting-views-to-publish-revit-project-on-a360)
- [Select Rooms and Views to Publish to the Cloud](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/09/revit-20181-nuget-packages-rooms-and-views-in-forge.html#2)